# Does my code need refactoring before adding unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have this code that works fine, but I would like to create some unit test for this class. Most of the code is in `private` or `void` type methods. Please help me refactor my class to make it more testable.

```
namespace Insperity.HCRBlackBox.HCRServices.Biz
{
    public class OrganizationChartBiz : IOrganizationChartBiz
    {
        private readonly OrganizationChartRepository _repository;

        public OrganizationChartBiz()
        {
            _repository = new OrganizationChartRepository();
        }

        public AcknowledgeOrganizationChartType NotifyOrganizationChart(NotifyOrganizationChartType notifyOrganizationChartType)
        {
            foreach (var organizationChart in notifyOrganizationChartType.DataArea.OrganizationChart)
            {
                foreach (var unit in organizationChart.OrganizationUnit)
                {
                    var existing = GetExistingOrganization(unit.OrganizationUnitID.Value);
                    if (existing.Equals(null))
                    {
                        TransformToOrganizationAndSave(unit);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TransformToOrganizationAndUpdate(unit, existing);
                    }
                }
            }
            return new AcknowledgeOrganizationChartType();

        }

        public AcknowledgeOrganizationChartType SyncOrganizationChart(SyncOrganizationChartType syncOrganizationChartType)
        {

            foreach (var organizationChart in syncOrganizationChartType.DataArea.OrganizationChart)
            {
                foreach (var unit in organizationChart.OrganizationUnit)
                {
                    var existing = GetExistingOrganization(unit.OrganizationUnitID.Value);
                    if (existing!=null)
                    {
                        TransformToOrganizationAndUpdate(unit, existing);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TransformToOrganizationAndSave(unit);
                    }
                }
            }

            return new AcknowledgeOrganizationChartType();
        }

        private void TransformToOrganizationAndUpdate(OrgChartOrganizationUnitType org, Organization existing)
        {
            List<RelatedOrganization> relatedOrganizations = new List<RelatedOrganization>();
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

            var organization = existing;
            if (org.ParentOrganizationUnit.OrganizationUnitID.Value!=null)
                organization.ParentOrganizationId = org.ParentOrganizationUnit.OrganizationUnitID.Value;
            organization.OrganizationName = org.OrganizationUnitName.Value;
            organization.LastModified = now;

            if (org.RelatedOrganizationUnit != null)
            {
                foreach (var relatedOrganizationUnitType in org.RelatedOrganizationUnit)
                {
                    var controlGroup = new RelatedOrganization
                        {
                            ControlGroupId = relatedOrganizationUnitType.OrganizationUnitID.Value,
                            StartDate =
                                Convert.ToDateTime(relatedOrganizationUnitType.OrganizationUnitID.validFrom),
                            Organization = organization,
                            EndDate =
                                relatedOrganizationUnitType.OrganizationUnitID.validTo != null
                                    ? Convert.ToDateTime(relatedOrganizationUnitType.OrganizationUnitID.validTo)
                                    : new DateTime?(),
                            LastModified = now
                        };
                    relatedOrganizations.Add(controlGroup);
                }
            }

            if (org.UserArea != null)
            {
                var userArea = org.UserArea as OrganizationChartUserArea;
                if (userArea != null)
                {
                    organization.EducationIndicator = userArea.EducationIndicator.Equals(false) ? "F" : "T";
                }
            }

            _repository.UpdateOrganization(organization,relatedOrganizations);
        }

        private void TransformToOrganizationAndSave(OrgChartOrganizationUnitType org)
        {
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

            var organization = new Organization
            {
                OrganizationId = org.OrganizationUnitID.Value,
                ParentOrganizationId = org.ParentOrganizationUnit.OrganizationUnitID.Value,
                OrganizationName = org.OrganizationUnitName.Value,
                LastModified = now
            };

            if (org.RelatedOrganizationUnit != null)
            {
                foreach (var relatedOrganizationUnitType in org.RelatedOrganizationUnit)
                {
                    var controlGroup = new RelatedOrganization
                    {
                        ControlGroupId = relatedOrganizationUnitType.OrganizationUnitID.Value,
                        StartDate =
                            Convert.ToDateTime(relatedOrganizationUnitType.OrganizationUnitID.validFrom),
                        OrganizationId = relatedOrganizationUnitType.OrganizationUnitID.Value,
                        EndDate =
                            relatedOrganizationUnitType.OrganizationUnitID.validTo != null
                                ? Convert.ToDateTime(relatedOrganizationUnitType.OrganizationUnitID.validTo)
                                : new DateTime?(),
                        LastModified = now
                    };
                    organization.RelatedOrganizations.Add(controlGroup);
                }
            }
            if (!org.UserArea.Equals(null))
            {
                var userArea = org.UserArea as OrganizationChartUserArea;
                if (userArea != null)
                    organization.EducationIndicator = userArea.EducationIndicator.Equals(false) ? "F" : "T";
            }

            _repository.SaveOrganization(organization);
        }

        private Organization GetExistingOrganization(string organizationUnitId)
        {
            return _repository.GetExistingOrganization(organizationUnitId);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _repository.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **1.** I'd change the wording in your question. "Please help me refactor" gives the impression that you want other people to do your work for you. **2.** I recommend reading the book *Working Effectively with Legacy Code* by Michael Feathers for tips on how to introduce tests to a codebase.

Comment: @Lstor I'm not asking anyone to write my unit test just to help make the code more testable. I hope I didn't give you that impression.

Comment: I know, that's why I suggest the rewording :) Otherwise I would have just downvoted.

Comment: @Lstor Thanks, I took your advice. Hopefully the new title is more accurate.

Comment: Names are confusing, collections not having plural etc... Does a `NotifyOrganizationChartType` message *target* a domain entity. You seem to be missing an aggregate. What does the collection of `organizationChart`s that is the `notifyOrganizationChartType.DataArea.OrganizationChart` signify in the domain, to the user for example?

Comment: @Malachi Unit tests are always the **first** step in [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring): _"Before applying a refactoring to a section of code, a solid set of automatic unit tests is needed."_ That's how you ensure that you didn't break anything during the refactoring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to @palacsint's advice, namely you should make the implicit dependencies of system under test explicit, I'll add a few more.

- In my experience easiest way to make a business method that uses system time testable is to **just pass the current time as a parameter**. "Time" is not part of your domain after all. 
  This refactoring is a form of [Replace Static Variable with Parameter](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceStaticVariableWithParameter.html) This will also save you the trouble of setting up a mock time provider service for test scenarios.
- The following means `org.RelatedOrganizationUnit` is some kind of collection

  ```
  if (org.RelatedOrganizationUnit != null)
  {
     foreach (... in org.RelatedOrganizationUnit)
  ```

  Make it default to an empty list, and you would not need to check for nulls. Less `if`s, less test cases needed.
- Factor out the repeating chunks about related organizations and `EducationIndicator` out smaller units are easier to test.
- Duplication is bad in itself. The following two snippets look like they were copy/pasted; then an error was fixed, for just one copy.

  ```
  // this should throw NullReferenceException if org.UserArea is null
  if (!org.UserArea.Equals(null)) 

  if (org.UserArea != null)
  ```

Comment: Thanks you make great points. The only one I can't do is default RelatedOrganizationUnit to empty. I do not own that class and am not the source of the data, this is a wcf service. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 5):

I'm not too familiar with C#, so just a few generic notes:

1. If you can, use a dependency injection (DI) framework and inject the `OrganizationChartRepository` instead of creating it inside the constructor. It would make the classes less coupled and therefore easier to test. If you can't use DI, you can create another constructor:

   ```
   @VisibleForTesting
   public OrganizationChartBiz(OrganizationChartRepository repository) {
       _repository = repository;
   }
   ```

   In the tests you can create the `OrganizationChartBiz` instance with a mocked repository and verify how the `OrganizationChartBiz` instance uses the mock. ([`@VisibleForTesting`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html) is from Guava. I guess C# has something similar or you can create your own markup for marking code which is exists only for the sake of testing.)
2. Instead of `DateTime` use a `TimeSource` or [`Ticker`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Ticker.html) interface to wrap the `DateTime`. See: [Use a fake system clock](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=234). You can pass this ticker to the constructor and pass a mocked ticker in the tests to make the behaviour repeatable.